# What are the perpendicular components of a tensor?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, tensor-calculus

In a paper by Landau et. al. (*Hydrodynamic theory of multiple formation of particles*), the conservation of energy-momentum is used:
$$
P^{\nu}\equiv\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0,
$$
This is a vector equation (the index $\nu$ runs from 0 to 3). My doubt is when he apparently decomposes this equation in components parallel and perpendicular to a 4-velocity $u^{\mu}$. The parallel component seems easy to find, we just contract the equation with the 4-velocity:
$$
P_{\parallel} = u_{\nu}P^{\nu}=0
$$
In analogy with the vector calculus I am used to (in ordinary 3 dimensions), I expected that the perpendicular component would be
$$
P_{\perp}^{\lambda}=(P-P_{\parallel})^{\lambda}=\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\lambda}-u^{\lambda}u_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}
$$
However, in the paper, he writes

[image: Hydrodynamic theory of multiple formation of particles - Landau et. al.]

Why is the sign different? Both are obviously equal to zero, due to the energy-momentum conservation, but they may result in different conclusions.

EDIT: Landau uses Latin indices for both time and spatial components and the metric signature is (+++-), so this isn't due to conventions, I believe.

Comment: Note that an index is lowered. Maybe he's only looking at the spatial components and using the $(+,-,-,-)$ metric signature? The use of Roman indices would seem to support that (in modern notation, but Landau might have done things differently).

Comment: Landau uses Roman indices for the time component as well.